# Yii2 - calling method on afterAction

Tags: yii, yii2

I am trying to perform **afterAction** event in the controller, but nothing is happening (the function is not called). This is code for **afterAction**:

```
public function afterAction($action, $result)
    {
        $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);

        $this->_logDownloadActivity();

        return $result;
    }
```

And function I am trying to call:

```
    private function _logDownloadActivity()
    {
        $model = new ActivityLogsUserActivity();

        $model->user_id             = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $model->userActivityType_id = 3;
        $model->buildVersion        = 3333;
        $model->ipAddress           = $model->userIP();

        $model->insert();
    }
```

Comment: Check logs in runtime folder.

Comment: I looked in the app.log, but there are no new errors for today, or new logs for today testing.

Comment: Just to check if the function is being called or not, can you replace the function by a `var_dump($action)` or return any `string`? If that works, the problem is your function. And if that's the case, can you add more info about the `ActivityLogsUserActivity` class?

Comment: This is strange - I rewrote the functions, and now it is working o.O (everything is the same).